# Is is possible to have an Admin account manage both Exchange 2013 (on prem) and Office 365?

Tags: security, exchange, microsoft-office-365

We are in hybrid mode and a few people are asking me to create an additional account for them so they can administer O365 and use a different account for on prem exchange.

After troubleshooting on my own, I haven't been able to get a cloud admin account to load the /ecp virtual directory on the on-prem environment

Is it possible have an admin that can manage the /ecp of each site?

Comment: I have to ask: Are you creating accounts IN O365 in your hybrid setup?  You should be creating them on-premises.  Either on-premises then migrate to O365, or create from on-prem via New-RemoteMailbox or simliar (Enable-RemoteMailbox against an existing new AD account is probably more likely)

Answer (score 3):

If you create cloud-only accounts (i.e. not synchronized from local AD), they are completely unknown to your on-premises environment, thus they can't even log on to your local AD domain, and of course they can't manage anything in it.

You can do the reverse: have a local admin account and grant Office 365 administrative rights to that account.